# Find & Merge log files in a directory based on rotation

Tags: shell, perl

In a directory of log files are rotated daily by date FILEX*date +%F-%H%M.LOG and placed in a directory...
I am attempting to de-clutter the directory since I have too many files and merge the file by date.
Everyday I have at  2 files call it FILE A and B on different nodes. For example today....

Content is as follow (not actual, but for illustration purpose)

FILEA.2019-07-18-1701.LOG

```
111AAA
222BBB
```

FILEB.2019-07-18-1703.LOG

```
333CCC
444DDD
```

After merging  FILEA*date.LOG and FILEB*date.LOG are removed/deleted.

Manual way:

```
cat  fileA fileB > FILEC.date +%F-%H%M.LOG
```

I started writing the following code but stuck on how to proceed since it is returning filenames but I don't know how to pick the them by date and merge.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

opendir(DIR, "/mydirectory/");
my @files = grep(/\*.*LOG$/,readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);
foreach my $file (@files) {
   print "$file\n";
}
```

Above only prints the files in the directory.

FILEA.2019-07-18-1701.LOG
FILEB.2019-07-18-1703.LOG
more...from older dates.

the print returns all my logs directory. I planned to place them in an array, sort them by date and merge two... but that where I am stuck with how to proceed with the logic... [ either shell or perl help will do]
Expected output after combining the two files...

```
111AAA
222BBB
333CCC
444DDD
```

Comment: Your code does not do what you claim it does.

Comment: I was trying to find help not claim  that the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting the files by the date part of the filename can be done using what is called the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), named after Perl god Randal L. Schwartz who invented it.

Here is a script that sorts the filenames by date and then prints a suggested command to do with them. I assume you'll be able to adjust the rest to match your needs.

Also, to list files in a directory, it is easiest to use builtin function `glob()`, and probably most efficient too.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir="/mydirectory";
my @files = glob "$dir/FILE[AB]*.LOG";

# Schwartzian transform to sort by the date part of the file name
my @sorted_files =
    # return just the file name:
    map  { $_->[0] }
    # sort by date, then whole file name:
    sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] or $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] }
    # build a pair [filename, date] for each file, with date as "" when none found:
    map  { $_ =~ /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/; [$_, $1 || ""] }
    @files;

foreach my $file (@sorted_files) {
   print "$file\n";
   my $outfile = $file;
   # construct your output file name as you need - I'm not sure what you
   # want to do with timestamps since in your example, FILEA and FILEB had
   # different timestamps
   $outfile =~ s/[^\/]*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).*/FILEC.$1.LOG/;
   print "cat $file >> $outfile\n";
   # Uncomment this once you're confident it's doing the right thing:
   #system("cat $file >> $outfile");
   #unlink($file); # Not reversible... Safer to clean up by hand instead?
}
```

Important note: I wrote the `glob` patterns is such a way that it would not match `FILEC*, because otherwise the commented-out lines (`system`and`unlink`) could destroy your logs completely if your uncommented them and ran the script twice.

Of course, you can make all this a lot more concise once you're comfortable with the construct:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files =
    map  { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] or $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] }
    map  { $_ =~ /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/; [$_, $1 || ""] }
    glob "/mydirectory/FILE[AB]*.LOG";

foreach my $file (@files) {
    ...
}
```